# Provider error when retrieving data and product page firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I am working adding a Favorite button on top of the product page. I want the favorite button to add the product details to a Favorite widget.

Therefore, I placed the favorite button on the statfulWidget that retrieve the produce details.

After placing the AddFavorite change notifier, the root does not allow me to retrieve anymore the data from the product stating an error in the provider.

```
ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Food> above this FoodDetail Widget 

 Make sure that FoodDetail is under your MultiProvider/Provider<Food>.
  This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately
```

I do not understand why FoodDetail should in the Provider which was not necessary before adding the button for retrieve the data.

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => AuthNotifier(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => FoodNotifier(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => AddFavorite(),
        ),
```

```
class FoodDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  
  
  FoodDetail({Key key, this.item}) : super(key: key);

  final Item item;

  @override
  _FoodDetailState createState()=> _FoodDetailState();
  
  }
    class _FoodDetailState extends State<FoodDetail>{
    
    Item item;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      FoodNotifier foodNotifier = Provider.of<FoodNotifier>(context);
    
      _onFoodDeleted(Food food) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        foodNotifier.deleteFood(food);
      }
    var isInCart = context.select<Food, bool>(
      // Here, we are only interested whether [item] is inside the cart.
      (cart) => cart.items.contains(item),
    );

      return Scaffold(
        appBar: GradientAppBar(
          title: Text(foodNotifier.currentFood.name),
          actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: isInCart
                        ? null
                        : () { 
                          var cart = context.read<AddFavorite>();
                          cart.add(item);
                        },
                        splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        child: isInCart ? Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.yellow[500]) : Icon(Icons.star_border, color: Colors.yellow[500]),
                    ),
                  ],
```

```
class AddFavorite extends ChangeNotifier {
  /// The private field backing [catalog].
  Food _food;

  /// Internal, private state of the cart. Stores the ids of each item.
  final List<int> _itemIds = [];

  /// The current catalog. Used to construct items from numeric ids.
  Food get food => _food;

  set food(Food newFood) {
    assert(newFood != null);
    assert(_itemIds.every((id) => newFood.getById(id) != null),
        'The catalog $newFood does not have one of $_itemIds in it.');
    _food = newFood;
    // Notify listeners, in case the new catalog provides information
    // different from the previous one. For example, availability of an item
    // might have changed.
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// List of items in the cart.
  List<Item> get items => _itemIds.map((id) => _food.getById(id)).toList();


  /// Adds [item] to cart. This is the only way to modify the cart from outside.
  void add(Item item) {
    _itemIds.add(item.id);
    // This line tells [Model] that it should rebuild the widgets that
    // depend on it.
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: `_onFoodDeleted` move this function outside of build method @JL

Comment: it does not work. even removing it has no impact. I have the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, the issue was that the variable was required to be placed in stateless widget.

```
class _AddButton extends StatelessWidget {
    final Item item;

    const _AddButton({Key key, @required this.item}) : super(key: key);
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var isInCart = context.select(
        // Here, we are only interested whether [item] is inside the cart.
        (cart) => cart.items.contains(item),
    );

    return  FlatButton(
                        onPressed: isInCart
                        ? null
                        : () { 
                          var cart = context.read();
                          cart.add(item);
                        },
                        splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        child: isInCart ? Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.yellow[500]) : Icon(Icons.star_border, color: Colors.yellow[500]),
                    );
    }
}
```